# Javascript manually 'declick' then click child element whilst clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, click

Hi please feel free to suggest a better title I couldn't think of a way to word it.

### Issue

I have a Google Maps with pointer events set to none; this stops the map being scrolled into when you scroll over it and it works great.
I have a `div` that is wrapped around this element and when you click into it, it allows all pointer events on the map inside it therefore allowing you too scroll on the map.
Once you then leave the map with your mouse it re-enables pointer events none so that you can scroll over it.

The main issue is that when you click the map you then have to click it again to scroll.

I want to know if it possible to click on the overlay then to get it to un-click and click again for the user to save them being confused about having to click again. The reason this may be difficult is because when the user has clicked down it needs to un-click and click whilst they are still pressed down.

### Code

The issue I am having is that I have a Google Maps inside a `div` like so in the HTML:

```
<div id="gmap-holder" class="dealer-details__map gmap-scroll-block--on">
    <div id="map" class="dealer-details-gmap"></div>
</div>
```

JS working as explained in the header

```
$('.dealer-details__map').on('click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('gmap-scroll-block--on');
    $(this).addClass('gmap-scroll-block--off');
});
$('.dealer-details__map').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).addClass('gmap-scroll-block--on');
    $(this).removeClass('gmap-scroll-block--off');
});
```

### Pseudo of what I am trying to achieve

```
$('.dealer-details__map').on('click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('gmap-scroll-block--on');
    $(this).addClass('gmap-scroll-block--off');

    //pseudo start
    //$(this).unclick()
    //$(this).child().click();
    //pseudo end
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [Custom Controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls), so that you can create your own controls to handle interaction with the user. This involves Drawing Custom Control, Handling Events from Custom Controls and Positioning Custom Controls, it will also be easier to track as your function is in a button. You can take a look on the [sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom-state) code, for reference on how the implementation would be. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.dealer-details__map').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).child().click();
});
```